# htaccess - can't write redirect from GET to "/"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I'm trying this:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/product/([0-9]+) pages/product?id=$1
```

But site gives me 404 error, what's wrong with this line? This page loads fine if I go to page with get parameter: `product?id=1`, but `product/1` doesn't load.

htaccess file, it's located in site root:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^pages/product/([0-9]+) pages/product?id=$1
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your `.htaccess` file and also let us know where it is located relative to your webroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of your rules and add flags esp `L` to ensure both rules are not stepping over each other:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteRule ^pages/product/(\d+) pages/product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Might be one of those cases that needs `MultiViews` to be turned off?

Comment: Good point @CBroe yes that might be a possibility as `pages/product` is same.

Comment: no, this code is ok, sorry, I pasted it to another site's htacess) Thank you very much!